# Подключение bootstrap в net.core 3.x в wwwroot

Tags: bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc

Изучаю asp.net core по книге Фримена

и столкнулся с проблемой:

добавляю в wwwroot bootstrap без bower, посредством libman и не вижу просто bootstrap, лишь кучу разных с приставками

нашел в интернете, как подключить twitter-bootstrap и решил, что наверное за время с выхода книги они просто название сменили
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но тот пакет не работает

посмотрел в sample mvc-проекте и обнаружил, что там лежит самый настоящий bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как его подключить посредством libman?

(я знаю, что можно подключить сразу на представление посредством ссылки, но тогда нельзя подключить 4.0.0-alpha.6 версию, как в книге, а они, похоже, сильно отличаются, отличия прикрепил)
[image: ожидание]
[image: результат]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смените поставщика в форме `libman` на, к примеру, `unpkg`. Там притянется весь `bootstrap` вместе  `sass` и `less` наборами. Затем установите любое расширение для `Visual Studio 2019`, которое умеет компилировать `sass` или `less` (рекомендую набор из WebCompiler и Bundler&Minifier). И скомпилируйте файл `wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/sccs/bootstrap.scss` в файл `wwwroot/css/botstrap.css` (измените содержимое файла `compilerconfig.json`). На полученный файл можно ссылаться в `<link src="..." />`

Answer (score 0):

Помогло только копирование папки lib c sample-проекта и подключение

но проблемы отличий версий это не решило

если у кого-то есть инструкция по подключению bootstrap в wwwroot с libman - ответьте сюда, может у кого-то будет подобная проблема и моё решение будет неподходящим